ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred
I am trying to deploy code to an app engine. I have tried the same with so many changes. However, nothing seems to be working. Every time in the deployment stage it fails with the above error. Here's the YAML snippet of what I am using:
- name: Deploy to App Engine 
  env: 
    RETRY_COUNT: ${{ vars.RETRY_COUNT }} 
  run: | 
    set -x  # Enable debug mode 
    gcloud config set project ${{ vars.GCP_PROJECT_ID }} 
    npm run deploy-${{vars.ENVIRONMENT}}

And deploy-environment does as follows (for example):
"deploy-stage": "SEPARATOR=v && DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M) && VERSION=$(echo ${npm_package_version} | sed 's/\\./-/g') && GAE_VERSION=$DATE$SEPARATOR$VERSION && gcloud app deploy app_stage.yaml --version=$GAE_VERSION"

My app_stage YAML is as follows:
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: subscription
runtime_config:
operating_system: ubuntu22
runtime_version: 20
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
resources:
cpu: 2
memory_gb: 2
disk_size_gb: 10
network:
name: dev-vpc
subnetwork_name: dev-subnet1
session_affinity: true
skip_files:
- ^node_modules/.*$

I have tried the comments as per this case, and below are my findings:
Google cloud SDK is 484.0.0
app.yaml is valid (as above)
added skip_files

Any guidance will be really appreciated.
Update 1
I tried with verbosity=debug and here's the output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 998, in Execute
resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 822, in Run
resources = command_instance.Run(args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 122, in Run
return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 677, in RunDeploy
deployer.Deploy(
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 471, in Deploy
self.api_client.DeployService(new_version.service, new_version.id,
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 221, in DeployService
operation = operations_util.WaitForOperation(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 307, in WaitForOperation
completed_operation = waiter.WaitFor(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 261, in WaitFor
operation = PollUntilDone(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 322, in PollUntilDone
operation = retryer.RetryOnResult(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 249, in RetryOnResult
if not should_retry(result, state):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone
return not poller.IsDone(operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 243, in IsDone
return super(AppEngineOperationBuildPoller, self).IsDone(operation)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 182, in IsDone
raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
Blockquote

